# Jquery Dialog Webform

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have  Jquery Dialog with dropdown  etc. How can I take this value in code behind after ok button clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            height: 600,
            width: 900,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },

            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {


                    //want a dropdown selected item  value  so that i can use in the code behind and perform some query on that

                    $("[id*=btnLoadGrid]").click();  //doing postback for the server side button and loading dialog again..

                },
                Close: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }

            }

        });

        $("[id$=opener]").click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

    });

</script>
```

Basically I want the dropdown value  to use in code behind query and reloads the dialog again from code behind.

so my code behind file is ...

```
 Protected Sub btnLoadGrid_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadGrid.Click

    Dim stats As String =  "Here I want the status value from dropdown"


    Dim connectionstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DbConn").ToString
    'Dim objconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    Using objconnection As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)

        'Dim sqlDs As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()

        Dim Query As String = "Select top 5 ROW_NUMBER()over(order by Division,Name,NoOfDays) as [SR.No],Division,Name,Name,start_Date,End_Date,NoOfDays from emp_progm"
        Query &= " where status= '" & stats & "'"
        'sqlDs.SelectCommand = Query

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Query, objconnection)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()


    End Using
```

Reloading the grid after firing the query

```
    Dim script As String = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=opener]').click(); });"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "load", script, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us your `.dialog()` code so far and we can give you a hint as to where you can use AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do mine. Here is a working example as if I was sending an email, same principle, just different behind code.

**jQuery**

```
function sendEmail() {
   $("#email").dialog({
       modal: true,
       width: 550,
       buttons: {
            "Send": function () {
                var btn = document.getElementById("<%=lbSend.ClientID %>");
                if (btn) btn.click();
                $(this).dialog("close");
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
             }
          }
        });
        jQuery("#email").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));//this is key as it makes sure it finds the textboxes within the dialog. Without this, you will insert blank values. 
        }
```

**ASP**

```
<div class="popUpStyle" title="Send Email" id="email" style="display: none">
     <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To: " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendTo" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblFrom" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="From: "></asp:Label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendFrom" Text="Training.Registration@JeffWyler.com"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Subject: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbSubject" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
     <br />
      <asp:Label ID="lblBody" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Message:"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" runat="server" Width="515px" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSend" runat="server" Text="" Width="50px" Font-Size="smaller" OnClick="lbSend_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
```

**Code Behind C#**

```
protected void lbSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code to your database
}
```

In the ASP mark up, I do have a visible link button, however the Text isn't showing. (setting the link button to visible = false does fire the button) I'm using the dialog button to call the link button's command. If you don't want to dialog button, you can simply have the button (make sure you set the submit behavior to false) or a link button. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply perform a PageMethod call to a Web Service to perform the processes with selected values and then return true to let the post back happen.